# Access 2010 - Dynamically Set Combo Control Source and Row Source

Tags: vba, ms-access, combobox, ms-access-2010

I am limited in that I have to stick with the old (messy) table design.  On this one interface I am developing, there is a combo drop down that is a fixed values list.  The options are Group1, Group2, and Group 3.  Based on that, a dependent combo needs to be set to the correct row source and control source.

The form is locked, and the user can navigate the records (first, last, next previous, and an unbound combo to jump to a record). During those operations, I just want to refresh which list the dependent combo should pull from, and what value it should bind to, to show the correct value.

When the user clicks to make a "new" record, I won't show the dependent drop down (or make it enabled. haven't decided yet) until they choose a value in the first combo, telling us which group it is.

In order to control this, I created a function for use on this form.  This is that function:

```
Private Function MyGroup()
   'Mybitval is a table value that is a bit data type. It means group1       
   If Me.Mybitval = True Then
        Me.cboGroupType.Value = "Group1"
    ElseIf Me.Mybitval = False And Nz(Me.MyID1, 0) <> 0 Then
        Me.cboGroupType.Value = "Group2"
    ElseIf Me.Mybitval = False And Nz(Me.MyID1, 0) = 0 Then
        Me.cboGroupType.Value = "Group3"
    End If

    Select Case Me.cboGroupType
        Case "Group1"
            Me.cboGroupName.RowSource = "SELECT Group1.ID, Group1.G1Name FROM Group1 ORDER BY Group1.G1Name;"
            Me.cboGroupName.ControlSource = me.FKID1
        Case "Group2"
            Me.cboGroupName.RowSource = "SELECT Group2.ID, Group2.G2Name FROM Group2 ORDER BY Group2.G2Name;"
            Me.cboGroupName.ControlSource = Me.FKID2
        Case "Group3"
            Me.cboGroupName.RowSource = "SELECT Group3.G3ID, Group3.G3Name FROM Group3 ORDER BY Group3.G3Name;"
            Me.cboGroupName.ControlSource = me.FKID1
    End Select

    Debug.Print Me.cboGroupName.RowSource
    Debug.Print Me.cboGroupName.ControlSource
    Debug.Print Me.cboGroupName.Value
End Function
```

The idea is that I call this function on load, after I go to the first record, and then on any navigation button click or after update of the go to combo.

The problem is, that the cbogroupname never shows the value it has in the control source. When I try to load the form, my debug rowsource shows the correct sql, and the control source shows the value of the correct table field for the current record it's on, but 2 things don't seem to work. If I don't do the 3rd debug on the value, the form loads fine, but the combo doesn't show the right value, even though it's bound to a table column that has a value.  If do debug the value, I get a run-time error '2424': "The expression you entered has a field, control, or property name that [my application] can't find."

When I hit debug, it goes to the last line of the function:
Debug.Print Me.cboGroupName.Value

When I go to save a new record, I run through validation, and having this 1 combo, instead of 3 different ones with alternating the visibility, seems way easier.  Is there a reason this isn't working the way I am wanting it to?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

And just like that, I figured it out.  Of course it takes me all day, and posting this question to get it.

Here is the function, with the right syntax:

```
Private Function MyGroup()

   If Me.Mybitval = True Then
        Me.cboGroupType.Value = "Group1"
    ElseIf Me.Mybitval = False And Nz(Me.MyID1, 0) <> 0 Then
        Me.cboGroupType.Value = "Group2"
    ElseIf Me.Mybitval = False And Nz(Me.MyID1, 0) = 0 Then
        Me.cboGroupType.Value = "Group3"
    End If

    Select Case Me.cboGroupType
        Case "Group1"
            Me.cboGroupName.RowSource = "SELECT Group1.ID, Group1.G1Name FROM Group1 ORDER BY Group1.G1Name;"
            Me.cboGroupName.ControlSource = "FKID1"
        Case "Group2"
            Me.cboGroupName.RowSource = "SELECT Group2.ID, Group2.G2Name FROM Group2 ORDER BY Group2.G2Name;"
            Me.cboGroupName.ControlSource = "FKID2"
        Case "Group3"
            Me.cboGroupName.RowSource = "SELECT Group3.G3ID, Group3.G3Name FROM Group3 ORDER BY Group3.G3Name;"
            Me.cboGroupName.ControlSource = "FKID1"
    End Select

    Debug.Print Me.cboGroupName.RowSource
    Debug.Print Me.cboGroupName.ControlSource
    Debug.Print Me.cboGroupName.Value
End Function
```

Provided your form is bound to a table, such as mine is, the control source needs to = **"fieldname"** . It needs to be the field name in double quotes. Not me.fieldname as that ends up making the controlsource the value of that field name. It also can't be [table1]![field1] I tried that and that doesn't work either.

The above works beautifully.  Now to test the rest of the form!